# Finding any changes between two lists of the same length

Tags: python, list, algorithm, dictionary

Given 2 lists of the same length. Is it possible to return a dict containing any changes between the 2 lists. Each key being the value that was changed and the key's value being the value it was changed to. The following returns difference between the 2 lists:

```
differences = (first_set - sec_set).union(sec_set - first_set)
```

I am looking to go one step further and save the results as a dict. Here is an example of what I am looking for:

```
first_set = [1, 4, 6, 8, 9]
sec_set = [1, 4, 5, 4, 9]
```

Output:

```
dict = {'6':'5', '8':'4'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this, if you'd like an expanded answer this should do it.  Just looping through the first `list` and using `total` to keep track of the index, and then checking that index on the second `list`.  Then chucking them into a `dict` when they don't match.

```
first_set = [1, 4, 6, 8, 9]
sec_set   = [1, 4, 5, 4, 9]
mis_dict = {}

total = 0
for one in first_set:
    if one != sec_set[total]:
        mis_dict[one] = sec_set[total]
    total += 1

print(mis_dict)
```

Output:

```
{6: 5, 8: 4}
```

You can certainly one line this as well, or anything in between.  Just depends on what works best for you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dict comprehension:

```
out = {a: b for a, b in zip(first_set, sec_set) if a != b}
print(out)

# Output
{6: 5, 8: 4}
```

With module `itertools`:

```
from itertools import filterfalse

out = dict(filterfalse(lambda x: x[0] == x[1], zip(first_set, sec_set)))
print(out)

# Output
{6: 5, 8: 4}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine a generator expression with `zip` in the standard `dict` constructor:

```
dict((a, b) for a, b in zip(first, second) if a != b)
```

Comment: I feel this is most compact and possibly more Pythonic one. Upvote it.

Comment: @DanielHao thanks :) But after thinking a while, the dict comprehension version as suggested by Corralien looks somewhat cleaner to me.

Comment: Not quite sure. It's involving another layer of *abstraction* (mental-wise) by using filterfalse...

Comment: @DanielHao I mean, `{a: b for a, b in zip(first_set, sec_set) if a != b}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just go through the loop, checking if the elements are different, and if they are different write to the dictionary:

```py
for i in range(len(first)):
    if first[i] != second[i]:
        dct[str(first[i])] = str(second[i])
print(dct)
```